# NumberOfDiscIntersections - Definition of pair

Tags: combinatorics, logic, first-order-logic

Codility has a lesson titled [NumberOfDiscIntersections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viohr.png) described like so:

*We draw N discs on a plane. The discs are numbered from 0 to N − 1. An array A of N non-negative integers, specifying the radiuses of the discs, is given. The J-th disc is drawn with its center at (J, 0) and radius A[J].
We say that the J-th disc and K-th disc intersect if J ≠ K and the J-th and K-th discs have at least one common point (assuming that the discs contain their borders).*

Then they provide 6 easy numbers for N. [1,5,2,1,4,0]

[image: circle pairs image ->]

It all seems pretty simple at this point. Then follows this text:

*There are eleven (unordered) pairs of discs that intersect, namely:
discs 1 and 4 intersect, and both intersect with all the other discs;
disc 2 also intersects with discs 0 and 3.*

**PLEASE DO NOT POST SOLUTIONS** .. or attempts to cheat the lesson

I am concerned with the question, specifically the meaning of a pair. How they come up with only 11 pairs from this question baffles me.

I guess I need someone likely with a stronger mathematical background water down the definition of the very technical term 'pair'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are six disks (one is just a point)

If you have $6$ objects then there are $15$ ways of choosing $2$ of them.  This can be written as ${6 \choose 2}$ or ${\,}^6C_2$ or something similar as a [binomial or combinatorial co-efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and calculated as $\frac{6 \times 5}{2}$ or $\frac{6!}{2!4!}$

So there are ${6 \choose 2}=15$ potential pairs.

Looking at the diagram, four of these do not intersect

- Disks $0$ and $3$
- Disks $0$ and $5$
- Disks $2$ and $5$
- Disks $3$ and $5$

The other eleven pairs do intersect and these are described in "discs $1$ and $4$ intersect, and both intersect with all the other discs; disc $2$ also intersects with discs $0$ and $3$".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Henry. I am unfamiliar with what a number over a number inside of parenthesis means or how that would equal 15.

Comment: @Ususipse If you have $6$ objects then there are $15$ ways of choosing $2$ of them.  This can be written as ${6 \choose 2}$ or ${\,}^6C_2$ or something similar as a [binomial or combinatorial co-efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and calculated as $\frac{6 \times 5}{2}$ or $\frac{6!}{2!4!}$

Comment: Oh I see. Now the word pair makes sense in this context.Thanks a ton Henry!